# Show that the radius of the circle inscribed in a right triangle whit natural sides is a natural number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I thought this question very exciting. So, I would like to see any answers that you can show.

My proof is using Pythagorean triples.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does it mean for a circle to be subscribed on a right triangle? I've heard of inscribed and circumscribed.

Comment: Sorry, english problem. I mean inscribed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be solved in such a system. That is, the system of Diophantine equations.

$$a^2+b^2=c^2$$

$$r^2=\frac{a+b-c}{2}$$

The solutions can be written as.

$$a=2(k^2+q^2)q^2$$

$$b=k^2(k^2+2q^2)$$

$$c=k^4+2k^2q^2+2q^4$$

$$r=kq$$

Although it's better to record. Did the fix.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the radius of inscribed circle in a right triangle is:$$r=\frac{c_1+c_2-i}{2}$$ where $c_2$ and $c_2$ are cathetus and $i$ is the  hypotenuse. This expression is always multiple of $2$.